# CakePHP saving data from Google Analytics

Tags: php, mysql, api, cakephp, google-analytics

I've been working with this plugin: http://www.neilcrookes.com/2009/09/27/get-google-analytics-data-in-your-cakephp/ but honestly it's over my head.

Under Analytic.php it seems useTable is set to false, however, when it's true it throws an error. I am new to Cake and Cake plugins, so maybe I am interacting the wrong way.

I'd like to save the dimensions and metrics being pulled into a database using cake. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason you want to save the data from analytics rather than just display it from the API?

Comment: I'd like to feed it into a client management system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the model has useTable = false as it is using a datasource to get the data. you cant just set it to true, and it wont work any other way. if you want to save it create a new model with a db table like normal and then do something like the following.

in new model...

```
$data = ClassRegistry::init('AnaliticsModel')->findMethod();
```

then manipulate it how you need

```
$this->save($data);
```

its now in your db... you can then do `$this->find()` <-- normal cake stuff on the new model